# Java ArrayList of type Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arraylist, interface

I have two java endpoints in spring boot like this:

```
@PostMapping(path="/my-import-1")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String myImport1(@Valid @RequestBody ParameterDto1 params) {
    return this.serviceImpl.import(params);
}
```

and

```
@PostMapping(path="/my-import-2")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String myImport2(@Valid @RequestBody ParameterDto2 params) {
    return this.serviceImpl.import(params);
}
```

Both use the same service for importing, but have some differences in their parameters.

I created the service's import method like this

```
@Override
public String import(ParameterInterface params) throws Exception {
   ...
}
```

and the ParameterInterface like this

```
public interface ImportMetaData {
    public default ArrayList<FileInterface> getFiles() {
        return null;
    }
    public void setFiles(ArrayList<FileInterface> files);
}
```

Implementing this interface I created two ParameterDto classes (ParameterDto1 and ParameterDto2). The IDE shows everything is correct, also the start of my service works, but as soon as I send a request to one of the endpoints, I get the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
> Type definition error: [simple type, class
> com.beo.services.myImportService.rest.domain.dto.metadata.interfaces.ParameterInerface];
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of
> `com.beo.services.myImportService.rest.domain.dto.metadata.interfaces.ParameterInerface`
> (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either
> need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
> contain additional type information  at [Source:
> (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 5] (through reference chain:
> com.beo.services.myImportService.rest.domain.dto.metadata.ParameterDto["files"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
> with root cause

Can I any how create such an ArrayList from an interface and get these two endpoints running? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the ParameterDto1 and ParameterDto2. Jackson library requires a default, no-args constructor or a constructor with parameters annotated with `@JsonProperty("field_name")`, otherwise it cannot convert your message.

Solution:

Add a no-args constructor to ParameterDto1 and ParameterDto2 or annotate the constructor parameters with `@JsonProperty("field_name")`

Comment: Thanks for your response. No matter if I add a constructor like
public ParameterDto1() {} and public ParameterDto2() {} to my classes or I add them the way public ParameterDto1(@JsonProperty("files") ArrayList<FileInterface> files) {} to my classes, I get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Could you please check whether the method `public String myImport1(@Valid @RequestBody ParameterDto1 params)` uses ParameterDto1 or the ParameterInterface in the signature? I suspect that the issue lies over there.

Answer (score 0):

im guessing here because you didnt share the implementation of `ParameterDto1` or `ParameterDto2` - and for some reason your interface is called `ImportMetaData`  where according to the exception, your explanation and other files it should be `ParameterInterface`.

the problem is that getFiles/setFiles is considered as a property by jackson , its type is an interface and you are not sending any type information.

in general assuming `ParameterDto1` and `ParameterDto2`are using a concreate implementation of `FileInterface` you could just change your interface methods `getFiles`/`setFiles` so they are using generics  parameter and in each implementation set the concreate type for `FileInterface`  you are using , this will allow jackson to understand the concreate type for `FileInterface` .

incase `ParameterDto1` and `ParameterDto2` are not using a concreate implementation of `FileInterface` you should add `@JsonTypeInfo` or `@JsonSubTypes` (see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations section 5 for more info) - note that the client calling the api should also specify the actual type in the json-type field

### Suggested implementation

```
public interface ParameterInterface {
@JsonIgnore
public List<FileInterface> getParameters() default { return null;}
.....
}

public class ParameterDto1 implements ParameterInterface {
private List<FileImpl1> files;
public List<FileImpl1> getFiles(){return files;}
public void setFiles(List<FileImpl1> files){this.files=files;}
....
}



public class ParameterDto2 implements ParameterInterface {
private List<FileImpl2> files;
public List<FileImpl2> getFiles(){return files;}
public void setFiles(List<FileImpl2> files){this.files=files;}
...
}


public class FileImpl1 implements FileInterface{

...
}

public class FileImpl2 implements FileInterface{

...
}
```